# Why this does not print "equals"?

Tags: c

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void) {
      float media1,media2,media3,matematica,romana,istorie;
      printf("Notele primului elev snt/\n");
      scanf(" %f %f %f",&matematica,&romana,&istorie);
      media1 = (matematica+romana+istorie)/3;
      printf("media primului element %f",media1);
      printf("\n");
      if(media1>=9)
        printf("fasfsafsaf");
      else if (media1>=8){
        printf("fgegegeg");
      }
     else if((media1<   5.6) || (media1<=6.3f)){
        printf("equal");
     }  
return 0;
}
```

Why this does not print 6.3 ? If i provide something like `float x = 6.3`; and test `media1 <= 6.3` it will print equal.

Comment: The input is 6.3 6.3 6.3

Comment: well if you are solving your problem with floats, you now have 2.00000001 problems...

Comment: Try `printf("media primului element %.12f %.12f",matematica, media1);` --> `6.300000190735  6.300000190735`.

Comment: Thanks ,that was the answer I was thinking but the think that tricked me is that i added float x = 6.3; and then i added the condition media1 <= 6.3 but that was true since 6.3 is the same as x .

Comment: If you use `double`, then `printf("media primului element %.20f %.20f",matematica, media1);` --> `6.29999999999999982236 6.29999999999999982236`

Comment: else if((media1<    5.6) || (media1<= (float) 6.3 )){
    printf("equal");
} And why this prints equals ?